# Json Formatting issue in PHP calling from Java

Tags: java, php, json

I am calling mysql data in Java as Follows:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result).getJSONArray("server_response").getJSONObject(0);
                if (jo.getString("success").equals("1"))
....
```

PHP:

```
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'xxxx';
   $dbpass = 'xxxx';
      $conn =  mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,'test_db');

   if(! $conn ) {
          $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No connection.";
         header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
        exit;
   }

   $sql = "Select * from employee ".
      "where 1=1 ";


  // array for JSON response
$response = array();    
   $retval = mysqli_query($conn,$sql );

   if(! $retval ) {

         $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "User not found.";
   }
   else{       

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User has been found.";

        // echoing JSON response


   }
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
```

Getting result in browser as:

> {"server_response":{"success":1,"message":"User has been found."}}

but it seems to me not getting values in correct json format that Java can interpret hence code not executing further.

Comment: Your ·$response array only contains the "success" and "message" elements and this is what you send back to java. But you must somehoe send back also the results of mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified PHP file last line to:

```
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>array($response)));
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but, in the server response the String with Id "message" is written with brackets "". But the "success" one had no bracket, maybe Java considers it as an int and as you're trying to compare to a String ("1") it returns false.